# Returning JSON with jQuery .post results in "undefined"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

in php:

```
return json_encode($output);
```

Results in this:

```
[
    {
        "u_s_user": "UserName",
        "u_s_first_name": "First",
        "u_s_last_name": "Last",
        "u_s_email":"me@domain.org"
    }
]
```

Here is jQuery:

```
function PopulateUserFieldsToEdit() {
    var user_num = $("#choose_user_to_edit").val();
    $.post( url, {   
        _get_user_fields : 1, 
               _user_num : user_num, },
        function(data) {
            alert(data.u_s_first_name);
            $("#user_username").val(data.u_s_user);
            $("#user_firstname").val(data.u_s_first_name);
            $("#user_lastname").val(data.u_s_last_name);
            $("#user_email").val(data.u_s_email);
        }, "json" );
}
```

When I do `alert(data.u_s_email)`, for example I get `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what do you see in your networks tab for this request?

Comment: @thescientist  My network tab shows code 200 and the response is exact JSON above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want `data[0].u_s_user` instead of `data.u_s_user`

(similarly, prepend all of your other keys with `data[0]` instead of just `data`)

Comment: i was just thinking the same :)

Comment: That was it!  Thanks... marking correct.  I didn't see that in the jQuery .docs